# How to highlight only selected row in a large table set in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a table component with React and I'm encountering an issue with a large table set (> 500 rows). Indeed, When I try to highlight the row where I clicked on, I encounter a big leak in performances.

In order to achieve the row selection, I'm holding a state containing the currently active row in the top component which consists of a container for all the rows in my table. When I click on a cell, I'm updating this state with the row the cell is part of.

This cause a trigger of the render() method my top component and the whole application becomes slow due to huge amount of elements re-rendered.

How can I re-render just the selected row? Is there a general best-practice to avoid the re-render of all the components under by top component?

[image]

Comment: can you share the code snippet which you are using to highlight the table row or create a react-sandbox for it

Comment: Using a fixed key for each of the table row, should help in improving the performance as not all rows will be rerendered in this case

Comment: as @ShubhamKhatri mentioned, use a unique `key` for list elements ([more on that](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)), use [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) apply your own optimizations to avoid unnecessary re-render, extend `PureComponent` class, further you could apply memoization using [`reselect`](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect).

Comment: Instead of having the container component listen to the 'selected row changed' and rerendering, put a 'listener' at the row component level so that only 2 row rerender (the previous selected one and the new selection)

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri thanks for the answer. I tried to avoid a global re-rendering using `shouldComponentUpdate` without success. I was trying to apply the logic on the `active=true` attribute but I guess I did something wrong.

Comment: @AshKander thanks for the answer. If I apply the listener on the row level I can easily achieve a change in the state and trigger a new render with the new class applied. But when I click on another row, I'm currently not able to make the "old selected row" aware of this change without "inform" the state at a body level.

Answer (score 0):

What about using CSS? You can use :hover property over each row and change the background color each time the mouse is over or clicked. The performance stress is to low if you use the CSS property.

Good luck

Comment: Hello Lucas, thanks for your answer but I want to achieve a row selection which is conceptually different from a hover effect. I want to make the component aware about the selection in order to make further actions.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did build a grid component in react. My approach to get a fast responding grid on selection and keyboard navigation:

- Do not render rows that is outside the viewport (visible range).
- Use an unique key on all rows as mentioned in the comments.
- Have the selected row key as a component variable (not in state).
- On selection update selected row key variable and then update the DOM directly without re-rendering. I get a ref to the grid and then use getElementsByClassName to set remove active class from any active row. Then set active class + focus to the selected row.

I realize that your implementation differs from mine but hopefully you can get some ideas at least.